# How to declare a variable and increment it in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

How to initialize a numerical variable in Django templates.

```
{% with i=1 %}
    {% for cont in data %}

    {% if i|divisibleby:3 %}
         {{ forloop.i }}
    <!-- HTML -->

    {% elif i|divisibleby:2 %}
         {{ forloop.i }}
    <!-- HTML -->

    {% else %}
         {{ forloop.i }}
    <!-- HTML -->

    {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Getting this error due to {% with i=1 %}

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /tools-dash/

Unclosed tag on line 21: 'with'. Looking for one of: endwith.
```

The variable i is not being incremented by each {{ forloop.i }}. For each row in DB I get the same template in else part. How this can be changed to alternative ones.

Comment: you haven't closed the with tag . please close it. {% endwith %}

Comment: @pavan it worked, but {{ forloop.i }}  is not working. only getting data of else part what I should change to get alternative one for each data

Comment: actually there is no variable as forloop.i . The for loop sets a number of variables available within the loop. please check the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create a new variable. You can use your normal for loop, and check if `forloop.counter` is divisible by 3 or 2. Like so:

```html
{% for cont in data %}

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
        {{ forloop.counter }}
        <!-- HTML -->

    {% elif forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
        {{ forloop.counter }}
        <!-- HTML -->

    {% else %}
        {{ forloop.counter }}
        <!-- HTML -->

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you need to close django tage **with**
like
`{% with i=1 %} ......your code {% endwith %}`